# How can I show a bitmap in wxGrid header cell?

Tags: grid, wxpython

Using wxPython I want to render a bitmap only in the upper left grid corner cell of a `wxGrid`, but have no idea how to do this.

I get the Window-Object of the left upper grid corner cell with

```
mywindow = self.someGrid.GetGridCornerLabelWindow()
```

But now I cannot set a bitmap to these Window-Object. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a **GridLabelRenderer**. There is an example in the **wxPython demo** that has the following piece of code:

```
class MyCornerLabelRenderer(glr.GridLabelRenderer):
    def __init__(self):
        import images
        self._bmp = images.Smiles.getBitmap()

    def Draw(self, grid, dc, rect, rc):
        x = rect.left + (rect.width - self._bmp.GetWidth()) / 2
        y = rect.top + (rect.height - self._bmp.GetHeight()) / 2
        dc.DrawBitmap(self._bmp, x, y, True)
```

To use this renderer, you will have to do something like this:

```
g = MyGrid(self, size=(100,100))
g.SetColLabelRenderer(0, MyCornerLabelRenderer())
```

This will put the image into the first column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This will be working, but only with a python 3.x version, I think(by reading the example). But for this project I must work with Python 2.5...

Comment: According to http://wxpython.org/recentchanges.php, GridLabelRenderer was added in wxPython 2.9.0.1. There appears to be a version of 2.9 that supports Python 2.5 here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.9.1.1/

Comment: Thanks for help, problem is: This project is for a company where all people get their software from one managment, so it's not so easy to roll out to all PC's a newer version of wxpython. S I'm working with wx-Version 2.8 ... :(

Comment: You should take a look at how GridLabelRenderer is implemented. Maybe you can use it to roll your own. I suspect you will need to use a Device Context to draw in a certain location, but I don't really know.